# Regular expression with?

Tags: regex

I am going through *learncodethehardway's* [regular expression courses](http://regex.learncodethehardway.org/book/ex10.html).

One matching criteria is `[A-Za-z]+?`

The author explains that by adding the `?`, this matching criteria will be "non-greedy".

However, I think the following two are equivalent. Shouldn't it always generate the same output if I use it for parsing strings?

`[A-Za-z]+?`

`[A-Za-z]+`

Am I correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, no they are not the same.  If you include the "?", it will match as FEW characters as possible.  Here's an example:

```js
var string = 'abcdefg';

alert(string.match(/[A-Za-z]+/));
```

```js
var string = 'abcdefg';

alert(string.match(/[A-Za-z]+?/));
```

Now, the "?" can still match multiple characters, but only if it has too, like this:

```js
var string = 'abcdefg>';

alert(string.match(/[A-Za-z]+>/));
```

Now it gets a little confusing.  Check out this example that does NOT include the "?" (the dot character matches everything but a space or new line character):

```js
var string = '<abcdefg>sldkfjsldkj>';

alert(string.match(/<.+>/));
```

You can see that it matches everything.  However, with the "?", it will match only up to the first ">".

```js
var string = '<abcdefg>sldkfjsldkj>';

alert(string.match(/<.+?>/));
```

Now it's time for a practical example of why we would need the "?" symbol.  Suppose I want to match everything between `<strong>` HTML tags:

```js
var string = '<strong>I\'m strong<\/strong> I\'m not strong <strong> I am again.<\/strong>';

alert(string.match(/<strong>[\s\S]+<\/strong>/));
```

As you can see, that matched EVERYTHING between the first and last `<strong>` tags.  To match ONLY one, use the life-saving "?" symbol again:

```js
var string = '<strong>I\'m strong<\/strong> I\'m not strong <strong> I am again.<\/strong>';

alert(string.match(/<strong>[\s\S]+?<\/strong>/));
```

Comment: `\s` matches any space character, and `\S` matches any character that's not a space character.  If you put characters between brackets, it tells the browser to match any of the characters between the brackets.  So, essentially, `[\s\S]` matches ANY character.